# Why do we define measurable sets as a $\sigma$-algebra, not just an algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

When defining what “a measurable set” means, one quite naturally arrives at the definition of an algebra:

1. $\emptyset$ and $X$ are measurable
2. if $A$ is measurable, then $X \setminus A$ is measurable
3. if $A$ and $B$ are measurable, then $A \cup B$ is measurable

Each of these rules makes perfect sense to me. However, the actual definition of measurability uses the rules of a $\sigma$-algebra, adding the union of an countably infinite number of sets:

3. if $A_i$ are measurable, where $i \in \mathbb N$, then $\bigcup_i A_i$ is measurable

Why do we need this stricter definition? I know the definition of the Lebesgue integral uses the approximation by simple functions with *countably* many steps, but it isn't clear to me at all that this wouldn't also work with finite partitions.

Is there a simple and intuitive reason, why we *must* require the countable union? If not, is there a subtle, technical reason for it? Or do we require it simply because it is more convenient to work with?

There have been questions which touched upon this topic [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1689314/142487) [[2]](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/199280/229720) [[3]](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1420386/142487), but as far as I can tell, nobody has provided a direct satisfactory answer to this question.

Comment: How would you deal with showing that, say, the cantor set is measurable with only finite steps allowed?

Comment: Another aspect may come from taking the products. If we only allow finite unions of intervals on the line, then we only get finite unions of rectangles on the plane. But we also want to measure, say, a triangle or a disk. Both with grade school formulas for the area.

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4070946/integration-with-respect-to-a-finitely-additive-measure

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps that measure wants to capture limiting processes, and therefore ought to have an infinite aspect?

If you don't have countable unions, you essentially add nothing to what is already known?

There are two suggestions to begin ...